# Couldn't scroll all the way up in scroll view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

Okay so there is this list of checkboxes in a cardview which under a LinearLayout. and I've added a scrollview since it can't fit all of them and I want to add a slider later on. But the problem is that I can't get it to scroll all the way up as seen in the picture below.I have tried a few solutions like `android:fillViewport="true"` given in online forums and certain sites, but none of them seems to be working.

[image: picture]

Page_three.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/CardStyle.Home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/pref_check" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</ScrollView>
```

Pref_check.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_spacing_small"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/preferences"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle.Title" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkBeach"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/beach" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/bar" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkMuseum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/museum" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkRestaurant"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/restaurant" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkNightClub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/night_club" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkArtGallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/art_gallery" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkAmusementPark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/amusement_park" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkCasino"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/casino" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkClothingStore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/clothing_store" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkShoppingMall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/shopping_mall" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkAmusementCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/amusement_center" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkResort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/Resort" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    </FrameLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        />




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Remove the gravity from the ScrollView.

Comment: @TheWanderer still not working

Comment: What's the ScrollView inside?

Comment: Scrollview is the outermost. Scrollview contains CardView, and Linear layout

Comment: Can you show the Activity configuration then? It's obviously not default, since you have a TabLayout on the bottom and no ActionBar.

Comment: @TheWanderer just updated

Comment: How are you then attaching the ScrollView to the Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it :

Instead of adding the `cardview` in the Page_three.xml , I instead wrapped it around `LinearLayout` in  Pref_check.xml.

Page_three.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_spacing_small">
       <include layout="@layout/pref_check" />

       <include layout="@layout/slider" />
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Pref_check.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/CardStyle.Home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/view_spacing_small"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/preferences"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextStyle.Title" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkBeach"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_spacing_medium"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:text="@string/beach" />
          .
          .
          .

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be some issue with the `styles configuration` of your project because your layout is coming below the `statusbar`.

Use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the root view of your layout, `ScrollView`in your case.

***EDITED***

You have to add `android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"`(Any size for `BottomNavigationView`) to your `ScrollView` so that the layout comes above the `BottomNavigationView`.

I have tried and test the code and its working

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="adad" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkBeach"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="beach" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="bar" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkMuseum"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="museum" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkRestaurant"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="restaurant" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkNightClub"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="night_club" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkArtGallery"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="art_gallery" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkAmusementPark"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="amusement_park" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkCasino"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="casino" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkClothingStore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="clothing_store" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkShoppingMall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="shopping_mall" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkAmusementCenter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="amusement_center" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkResort"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="Resort" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @Teeban how you are using `ScrollView` xml with your `Activity` xml?

Comment: Just try to fix your `styles` configuration that is used with this `activity`. I am sure it is happening because of that.

Comment: Okay I'm using the bottom navigation and in one of the bottom navigation page(Page_three.xml) is the checkbox with scrollview. I use it Bottom navigation page xml

Comment: also what do you mean by layout is coming below the statusbar ?